# Set State in FlatList

Tags: react-native, components, state, react-native-flatlist

I'm creating simple component with multiple object of state i want to set state value through inside FlatList but reason is that when run the code click on button where i'm calling callback function page goes blank then get error

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, Button, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import ColorCounter from '../components/ColorCounter';

const SquareScreen = () =>{
    const [Colors,SetColors] = useState([
        {
            Name : 'Red',
            Value : 0
        },
        {
            Name : 'Green',
            Value : 0
        },
        {
            Name: 'Blue',
            Value : 0
        }
    ]);

    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList keyExtractor={Key => Key.Name} data={Colors} renderItem={({item}) => {
                return (

                    <ColorCounter OnIncrease={() => {SetColors(item.Value + 1)}} OnDecrease={() => {SetColors(item.Value - 1)}} Name={item.Name} />
                );
            }}/>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: Do you have an error in the logs? Can you copy it?

Comment: nothing when i click in it its goes into blank page so what i do i moderate code bit more

<ColorCounter OnIncrease={() => {SetColors(Colors[item].Value + 1)}} OnDecrease={() => {SetColors(Colors[item].Value - 1)}} Name={item.Name} />

Now getting error Undefined error Colors[item].Value